# Can I import excel file to phpmyadmin?

Tags: excel, phpmyadmin, spreadsheet

I have an speadsheet file contains some data such as ID, name, lastname. Can I import excel file to phpmyadmin (SQL)?
How to do it?

Comment: This helped me successfully upload file: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=diEwQk4uY14

Comment: I know its late, but I posted an [article](http://www.davalign.com/articles/import-excel-data-into-mysql-using-phpmyadmin/) a while back on how to accomplish this. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

Export the spreadsheet as CSV first, then import as CSV.

Comment: Did you look in the file to see if that's true?

Comment: I my file, I have two column (ID, name). And in phpmyadmin I build table 'test' that have two column (ID, name) too.

When I import .CSV file to phpmysql it show 'Invalid field count in CSV input on line 1.'

Comment: Maybe the name contains an unescaped comma? Or you've got your separators mixed up (ie. different separators in the file and in the import settings)?

Answer (score 1):

*Excel* tables **must not** have blank cells - these will be skipped when *CSV* file is created giving the wrong number of fields in the row(s) concerned. Also *Excel* cells must not contain any symbols used as delimiters (typically doublequote`"` and comma`,`. The delimiters may vary according to excel version/language.

Excel 2016 *CSV* looks like:

```
22,Fred,Bloggs,22,Acacia Avenue
```

...but *phpMyAdmin* requires:

```
"22","Fred","Bloggs","22","Acacia Avenue"
```

**My tip** - add extra columns before and after your excel table and fill each column with something unique like `ZZ`. Then create *CSV*. Use a text editor with *Find/Replace* to change each comma to `","`. This gives you `ZZ","22","Fred","Bloggs","22","Acacia Avenue","ZZ`. Then Find/Replace `ZZ","` with `"` and then `","ZZ` with *"*.

Now your *CSV* matches what *phpMyAdmin* needs.

Answer (score -1):

is there a white space in what you think could be an empty excel field? Also you want to check that your delimiter isnt represented in the text field. Meaning that if you have stored a persons name or id with a comma, like "Nixon, Richard", it will think that is for two seperate colums, giving you a count mismatch on using the first delemited lines as more than 2 colums.

The error message is telling you that it found a different number of columns when compared to the rows of data. More than likely your delimiter is inside of your datacells.